# Translate sections into German

Tags: babel, sections-paragraphs, german, translate

This is my Code:

```
%% Packages
%% ========

%% Babel provides support for languages.  'english' uses British
%% English hyphenation and text snippets like "Figure" and
%% "Theorem". Use the option 'ngerman' if your document is in German.
%% Use 'american' for American English.  Note that if you change this,
%% the next LaTeX run may show spurious errors.  Simply run it again.
%% If they persist, remove the .aux file and try again.
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
 \addto\captionsngerman{% 
  \def\abstractname{Abstract}%
  }
%% Some other packages

%% Document information
%% ====================

%% Some other formats

\input{sections/0_abstract}


\input{sections/acro}
{
    \linespread{0.7}\selectfont{}
    \glsnogroupskiptrue
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
}
\printglossary

\input{sections/1_introduction}
\input{sections/2_analyse_of_project}
\input{sections/3_conceptplaning}
\input{sections/4_controller_implementation}
\input{sections/5_controller_testing}
\input{sections/6_evaluation_and_result}
\input{sections/7_summary_conclusion}

\appendix
\input{sections/a_appendix}
\backmatter

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\typeout{}
\bibliography{./sections/bibliography.bib}

\end{document}
```

one of my sections is

```
\chapter{Konzept}
\section{Regelstrecke und Modellierung der Gleichstromantriebs}
\subsection{Regelstrecke}
\acrshort{iso}11898 es beschreibt einen physikalischen datenlink...
```

My Problem is that in my sections are in German not English, so my text is underlined red. How I can change that?

Comment: Please make sure your example is (1) minimal, your're loading a lot that does not seem to be relevant to your question, (2) the example is self contained. We don't have **any** of the files you input and thus have no chance to be able to compile and test your example.

Comment: @daleif thanks for your input. I make changes to it

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Based on the sentence just after your code, I am under the impression that the problem is that when you open your documents in your editor, the words are underlined in red because the spell check of your editor is set to spell check English text and not German text. If this is the case, you should search how to change the language of the spell check of your editor. If this is not the case, please clarify your problem.

Comment: @KersouMan thx this was the problem